# SQL Select in an Insert statement

Tags: sql

How can I combine these two scripts? I basically don't want to hard code the number `34` in `Query 2`. I want the script to take the next number of job_id. `Query 1` returns `34`, so `Query 2` should take `35` as the `job_id`.

**Query 1**

```
select top 1 job_id from job
order by job_id desc
```

**Output of query 1** - 34

**Query 2**

```
insert into job (job_id, name)
values (35, 'Defend them')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use `order by job_id desc` and `top 1` to get the value you want. 
You need `max(job_id) + 1`

```
insert into job (job_id, name)
select max(job_id) + 1, 'Defend them'
from job
```

Answer (score 2):

You do this by defining `job_id` as an `identity` column:

```
create table jobs (
     job_id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
     name varchar(255)
);
```

Then you can just do:

```
insert into jobs (name)
    values ('Defend them');
```

And SQL Server assigns the job id.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
insert into job (job_id, name)
select top 1 job_id+1, 'Defend them'
from job
order by job_id desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select     top 1 job_id, 'Defend them' 
into       job (job_id, name)
from       job
order by   job_id DESC
```

Comment: A brief explanation of how/why this works would be very helpful to future readers.